# Intellij Scala Type Info stopped working

Tags: scala, intellij-idea

Scala's Type Info from the View menu and by pressing ctrl-shift-p has just stopped working. I press and nothing appears ever. I upgraded the IDE and the plugin but it doesn't make a difference. Any help on how to fix it would be appreciated.

Comment: Do you have any exceptions in idea.log file? You can get there by Help -> Show log in explorer.

Comment: These are what I'm seeing when I start it up:
java.io.FileNotFoundException: /Users/xxx/Library/Caches/IdeaIC2017.1/compile-server/prog_c81a59f2/backward-refs/version (No such file or directory)
java.io.FileNotFoundException: /Users/xxx/Library/Caches/IdeaIC2017.1/compile-server/bbb_a0cc875f/backward-refs/version (No such file or directory)
java.io.FileNotFoundException: /Users/xxx/Library/Caches/IdeaIC2017.1/compile-server/ccc_c70ad62f/backward-r

Comment: nothing that looks suspicious ..

Answer (score 1):

Try File > Project Structure > Global Libraries and make sure you have at least one scala-sdk present.

In the same screen, select Modules and check the Dependencies tab and make sure your scala-sdk is present (it's usually toward the top of the list).

Comment: It's all set but doesn't seem to make a difference. What's een stranger is that it shows the type when I hover over a variable, but ctrl-shift-p or the menu item don't do anything.